# Makefile issue when adding option to show percentage

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile

I tried to add to my Makefile an option to display the percentage of the compile process.
However it doesnt compile correctly now, it seems i have created in some way a loop.

My Makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
SYSTEM = $(shell uname)
C++ = g++
CC = gcc
DFLAGS = -DGHOST_MYSQL
OFLAGS = -O3
LFLAGS = -L. -L../bncsutil/src/bncsutil/ -L../StormLib/stormlib/  -L/usr/local/lib/Poco/ -lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation -lbncsutil -lpthread -ldl -lz -lStorm -lmysqlclient_r -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lgmp
CFLAGS =

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
DFLAGS += -D__APPLE__
OFLAGS += -flat_namespace
else
LFLAGS += -lrt
endif

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),FreeBSD)
DFLAGS += -D__FREEBSD__
endif

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),SunOS)
DFLAGS += -D__SOLARIS__
LFLAGS += -lresolv -lsocket -lnsl
endif

CFLAGS += $(OFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/

ifeq ($(SYSTEM),Darwin)
CFLAGS += -I../mysql/include/
endif

## PRINT_PROGRESS is initially undefined
ifndef PRINT_PROGRESS
# T estimates how many targets we are building by replacing PRINT_PROGRESS with a special string
T := $(shell $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) --no-print-directory \
        -rRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) \
        PRINT_PROGRESS="echo COUNTTHIS" BUILD="test x ||" | grep -c "COUNTTHIS")
N := 1
## PRINT_PROGRESS is now defined to show the progress and update N
PRINT_PROGRESS = echo "`expr "   [\`expr $N '*' 100 / $T\`" : '.*\(....\)$$'`%]"$(eval N := $(shell expr $N + 1))
endif

OBJS = bncsutilinterface.o bnet.o bnetprotocol.o bnlsclient.o bnlsprotocol.o commandpacket.o config.o crc32.o csvparser.o game.o game_base.o gameplayer.o gameprotocol.o gameslot.o ghost.o ghostdb.o ghostdbmysql.o gpsprotocol.o language.o map.o packed.o replay.o savegame.o sha1.o socket.o stats.o statsdota.o util.o
COBJS =
PROGS = ./ghost++

all: $(OBJS) $(COBJS) $(PROGS)

./ghost++: $(OBJS) $(COBJS)
        $(C++) -o ./ghost++ $(OBJS) $(COBJS) $(LFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(COBJS) $(PROGS)

$(OBJS): %.o: %.cpp
        @$(PRINT_PROGRESS) $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(COBJS): %.o: %.c
        @$(PRINT_PROGRESS) $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

./ghost++: $(OBJS) $(COBJS)

all: $(PROGS)

bncsutilinterface.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h bncsutilinterface.h
bnet.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h language.h socket.h commandpacket.h ghostdb.h bncsutilinterface.h bnlsclient.h bnetprotocol.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h replay.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h
bnetprotocol.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h bnetprotocol.h
bnlsclient.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h socket.h commandpacket.h bnlsprotocol.h bnlsclient.h
bnlsprotocol.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h bnlsprotocol.h
commandpacket.o: ghost.h includes.h commandpacket.h
config.o: ghost.h includes.h config.h
crc32.o: ghost.h includes.h crc32.h
csvparser.o: csvparser.h
game.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h language.h socket.h ghostdb.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h game.h stats.h statsdota.h
game_base.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h language.h socket.h ghostdb.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h replay.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h next_combination.h
gameplayer.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h language.h socket.h commandpacket.h bnet.h map.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h gpsprotocol.h game_base.h
gameprotocol.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h crc32.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h
gameslot.o: ghost.h includes.h gameslot.h
ghost.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h crc32.h sha1.h csvparser.h config.h language.h socket.h ghostdb.h ghostdbmysql.h bnet.h map.h packed.h savegame.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h gpsprotocol.h game_base.h game.h
ghostdb.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h ghostdb.h
ghostdbmysql.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h config.h ghostdb.h ghostdbmysql.h
gpsprotocol.o: ghost.h util.h gpsprotocol.h
language.o: ghost.h includes.h config.h language.h
map.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h crc32.h sha1.h config.h map.h
packed.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h crc32.h packed.h
replay.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h packed.h replay.h gameprotocol.h
savegame.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h packed.h savegame.h
sha1.o: sha1.h
socket.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h socket.h
stats.o: ghost.h includes.h stats.h
statsdota.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h ghostdb.h gameplayer.h gameprotocol.h game_base.h stats.h statsdota.h
util.o: ghost.h includes.h util.h
```

The part I added here was:

```
## PRINT_PROGRESS is initially undefined
ifndef PRINT_PROGRESS
# T estimates how many targets we are building by replacing PRINT_PROGRESS with a special string
T := $(shell $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) --no-print-directory \
        -rRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) \
        PRINT_PROGRESS="echo COUNTTHIS" BUILD="test x ||" | grep -c "COUNTTHIS")
N := 1
## PRINT_PROGRESS is now defined to show the progress and update N
PRINT_PROGRESS = echo "`expr "   [\`expr $N '*' 100 / $T\`" : '.*\(....\)$$'`%]"$(eval N := $(shell expr $N + 1))
endif
```

And the change of these lines:

```
$(OBJS): %.o: %.cpp
        $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(COBJS): %.o: %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

to

```
$(OBJS): %.o: %.cpp
        @$(PRINT_PROGRESS) $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(COBJS): %.o: %.c
        @$(PRINT_PROGRESS) $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

The displayed output when compiling is now this:

```
$ make
g++: error: bncsutilinterface.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: bnet.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: bnetprotocol.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: bnlsclient.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: bnlsprotocol.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: commandpacket.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: config.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: crc32.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: csvparser.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: game.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: game_base.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: gameplayer.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: gameprotocol.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: gameslot.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ghost.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ghostdb.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ghostdbmysql.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: gpsprotocol.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: language.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: map.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: packed.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: replay.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: savegame.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: sha1.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: socket.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: stats.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: statsdota.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: util.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [ghost++] Error 1
  [3%] g++ -o bncsutilinterface.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c bncsutilinterface.cpp
  [7%] g++ -o bnet.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c bnet.cpp
 [10%] g++ -o bnetprotocol.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c bnetprotocol.cpp
 [14%] g++ -o bnlsclient.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c bnlsclient.cpp
 [17%] g++ -o bnlsprotocol.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c bnlsprotocol.cpp
 [21%] g++ -o commandpacket.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c commandpacket.cpp
 [25%] g++ -o config.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c config.cpp
 [28%] g++ -o crc32.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c crc32.cpp
 [32%] g++ -o csvparser.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c csvparser.cpp
 [35%] g++ -o game.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c game.cpp
 [39%] g++ -o game_base.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c game_base.cpp
 [42%] g++ -o gameplayer.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c gameplayer.cpp
 [46%] g++ -o gameprotocol.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c gameprotocol.cpp
 [50%] g++ -o gameslot.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c gameslot.cpp
 [53%] g++ -o ghost.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c ghost.cpp
 [57%] g++ -o ghostdb.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c ghostdb.cpp
 [60%] g++ -o ghostdbmysql.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c ghostdbmysql.cpp
 [64%] g++ -o gpsprotocol.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c gpsprotocol.cpp
 [67%] g++ -o language.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c language.cpp
 [71%] g++ -o map.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c map.cpp
 [75%] g++ -o packed.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c packed.cpp
 [78%] g++ -o replay.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c replay.cpp
 [82%] g++ -o savegame.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c savegame.cpp
 [85%] g++ -o sha1.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c sha1.cpp
 [89%] g++ -o socket.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c socket.cpp
 [92%] g++ -o stats.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c stats.cpp
 [96%] g++ -o statsdota.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c statsdota.cpp
[100%] g++ -o util.o -O3 -DGHOST_MYSQL -I. -I../bncsutil/src/ -I../StormLib/ -c util.cpp
g++ -o ./ghost++ bncsutilinterface.o bnet.o bnetprotocol.o bnlsclient.o bnlsprotocol.o commandpacket.o config.o crc32.o csvparser.o game.o game_base.o gameplayer.o gameprotocol.o gameslot.o ghost.o ghostdb.o ghostdbmysql.o gpsprotocol.o language.o map.o packed.o replay.o savegame.o sha1.o socket.o stats.o statsdota.o util.o   -L. -L../bncsutil/src/bncsutil/ -L../StormLib/stormlib/  -L/usr/local/lib/Poco/ -lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation -lbncsutil -lpthread -ldl -lz -lStorm -lmysqlclient_r -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lgmp -lrt
g++: error: bncsutilinterface.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: bnet.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: bnetprotocol.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: bnlsclient.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: bnlsprotocol.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: commandpacket.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: config.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: crc32.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: csvparser.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: game.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: game_base.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: gameplayer.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: gameprotocol.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: gameslot.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ghost.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ghostdb.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ghostdbmysql.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: gpsprotocol.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: language.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: map.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: packed.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: replay.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: savegame.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: sha1.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: socket.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: stats.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: statsdota.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: util.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [ghost++] Error 1
```

The middle part is the actual wanted output.
However, the point is this is displayed in less seconds, like it just showing off but doesnt compile in any way.

What did I made wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the compilation commands as arguments to the `echo` in `PRINT_PROGRESS`.

```
@$(PRINT_PROGRESS) $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

You need to add a semicolon.

```
@$(PRINT_PROGRESS); $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

That being said I don't think this approach likely only works when each target has to print out one percentage marker (which is likely to be true much, if not all, of the time). Also this will may not play well with use of `-j`.

Comment: Well my output is now not visible. I dont see anything when i use `make`, however, it now really compile, the command require a bit time.

Comment: You should see the percentage output but correct, you will not see the compilation command. If you want both you need to double the recipe line. `@$(PRINT_PROGRESS) $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<; $(C++) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -c $<`.

Comment: Probably not even the percentage. As soon as I include the code for calculating the percentage the output is nothing anymore. Maybe there is something wrong with the snippet?

Comment: "Probably"? Do you or don't you get the percentage printed out with the line in my answer? Also you will probably have better luck using `$()` instead of backticks as they can nest and quote sanely.

Comment: No i dont get the percentage printed.

Changed now to this:
` PRINT_PROGRESS = echo "$(expr "   [$(expr $N '*' 100 / $T\)" : '.*\(....\)$$')%]"$(eval N := $(shell expr $N + 1)) ` but didn't change the case, still no single output.

Comment: Do you get output back if you drop the semicolon? What do you get if you drop the `@` symbol from the front of the line with the semicolon?

Comment: Same result. I dont have any output from my Makefile.

Comment: If going back to your original code isn't generating any output then something unrelated changed. You don't get any output even with the `@` removed? What do you get if you run `make SHELL+=-x`? Can you update with the newest makefile?